# Auto-increment Copied IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am updating a large group of records to have a new need from the previous year (in this case, a 2017 sponsorship). In order to do this, I am simply copying the last year's 2016 sponsorship records into a temporary_table and updating the fields to reflect the new year's values.

My question is this: When I copied the records into the temporary_table, the auto-increment ID's also copied over. I can't set this column to NULL, so when I insert these records into the live table, will the table recognize that there are duplicate ID's and increment the new ones? Is there another way to handle it?

Thank you!

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: That's not a DBMS, that's a SQL tool. But as that can only be used for SQL Server, it's safe to assume that you are using SQL Server.

Comment: If the field is an IDENTITY() field then you can just not insert the data into this field, it will autopopulate

Comment: Ah, my bad! Learn something new everyday in this gig.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those things that aren't obvious in the first instance but handy to know once you've hit the issue in the past.

Comment: Also, thank you for the answer! So I'm assuming since the field is the Primary Key field, then I if I just don't insert it as you said, it will autopopulate?

Comment: not necessarily. If you script out the table (Right click, Script Table As, Create To, New Window) you should see something like this; [Field1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL. If it doesn't have the IDENTITY bit then it won't auto populate

Comment: Thank you so much! It does indeed have the IDENTITY bit. I really appreciate all the help!